# MATLAB: MEX matrix division gives different result than m-file

Tags: matlab, matrix, mex, equation-solving, matlab-coder

I've used MATLAB's coder tool to create a MEX version of the matrix exponential function, to be used in another set of functions. The issue is, the MEX version gives different results than the original m-file.

After debugging it, I believe that the reason this is, is because the MEX file and the m-file do not do matrix division (\) the same. Or the MEX file has issues with it in the first place. All the variables leading up to the line where the matrix division occurs are equivalent on both sides.

This is the line where the issue occurs:

```
F = (V-U)\(2*U) + I
```

Where I is the identity matrix of the size of V and U.

What is the reason behind the discrepancy when a MEX file does matrix division, and how can I fix this issue? Can this line of code be re-written without the division?

Comment: Wow.. that is peculiar indeed.  Though this is slow, try doing this instead: `F = inv(V-U)*(2*U) + I`.  Doing `<\>` essentially takes the inverse matrix of the left side and multiplies by the right.  The `<\>` operator is used generally for non-square matrices in order to find the least squares solution to a linear system of equations.

Comment: @rayryeng I tried this and unfortunately it does not work. But doesnt inv(A) also cause matrix division? inv(A) = A\eye(size(A))

Is there perhaps another way to do this?

Comment: Not necessarily.  `inv(A)` computes the inverse matrix by itself.  There is a different algorithm to compute the inverse matrix instead of invoking the `<\>` operator.  How vastly different are the two answers?

Comment: Well its interesting because, the numbers are significantly small, and some of the elements of the result matrix are accurate. But some of the incorrect ones could have a % change of up to over 100%

Comment: That's very peculiar.  Did you try using known values of `V` and `U` as well as knowing what the result of `F` is and comparing between the two methods?

Comment: @rayryeng I did just now, but I'm not sure thats going to help much. With a smaller matrix it seems to work (or perhaps its just lucky), but with a 10x10, it still has SOME elements that are incorrect. Although the difference is small, its still there

Comment: Take a look at Amro's answer.  My guess is that it could be your version of MATLAB or it could be operating system dependent.  He was able to get both answers relatively close to each other (`error < 1e-14`)

Comment: @rayryeng, correct but this isnt the issue. The issue is that the % change from one matrix to the other is very large, sometimes over 100%!

Answer (score 4):

I have no problem generating C code from such an operation.

Here is a test function I tried:

#### myfcn.m

```
function F = myfcn(U,V)
    I = eye(size(U));
    F = (V-U)\(2*U) + I;
end
```

here's a test script we'll use to verify the results:

#### test_myfcn.m

```
U = rand(5);
V = rand(5);
F = myfcn(U,V);
```

I start by launching the code generation tool (`ccoder`), create a new project set to produce a MEX-file, then add the `myfnc.m` function from before as entry-point. Then I define both input variables types as:

```
double (:Inf x :Inf)
```

which specifies an MxN matrix of unbounded size of type double.

Finally we can build the project. This produces `myfcn_mex.mexw64`.

Testing both the original M-function and the generated MEX-function, I get pretty much the same result (difference is in the order of machine epsilon):

```
>> F = myfnc(U,V);
>> FF = myfcn_mex(U,V);
>> norm(F-FF)
ans =
   1.4391e-14
```

Comment: The problem is not that the difference is small, but that the percent change from what the actual answer should be is large. This discrepancy is causing an issue with the function/program I am using this MEX file in

Comment: @GBoggs: what do you mean by "percent change"? is that relative error? Please show a concrete example.. And always remember that floating-point numbers have limitations. For instance in MATLAB (and probably any other programming language that uses IEEE-754): `1.2 - 0.2 - 1` is not the same as `1.2 - 1 - 0.2`. Since the generated C code follows a different execution steps, there is no guarantee you'll get exact replica of the results from the original MATLAB function.

Comment: What I mean by this is: 100*(mex_out - out)./out, is the percent change. And for my application of this function, this percent change can get to over 100% difference, which is too much

Comment: @GBoggs: this comes back to the issue of [floating-point limitations](http://floating-point-gui.de/). The answer you get from MATLAB is no more correct than the answer you get from the generated C code. In a sense, they are both "wrong" because in the end you cannot represent an infinite amount of precision in a finite number of bits, and those round-off errors accumulate over time... Even more those errors grow differently depending on the order in which you evaluate the steps of the algorithm (MATLAB code does not execute the exact same procedure as the C code to solve the linear system)

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB made a minor change to the EXPM algorithm in the 2014a release.  MATLAB Coder implementations are separate, and the corresponding change has not yet been made in the algorithm for code generation, so some discrepancies are possible there.  The new implementation does `(V - U)\(2*U) + I`, whereas the old one does `(V - U)\(V + U)`.  These are mathematically equivalent but will give different round-off behaviors in general.

AFAIK, there is no systematic difference in the quality of solutions to linear systems in MATLAB versus MATLAB Coder.  The core algorithms are essentially equivalent, with round-off differences expected to creep in from various obscure sources.  The residual may be smaller for either MATLAB or MATLAB Coder in a given case.  If the difference in the solutions is large, it indicates that the problem being solved is ill-conditioned.  I can explain more about this if you like, but it is covered in every numerical analysis textbook.  Can you provide a concrete example?  At least can you find out what cond(V - U) returns there when your problem is solved in MATLAB?

Comment: Interesting. I somehow missed the point where the OP mentioned matrix exponential, so I didn't make connection with EXPM.. I remember a [blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2012/07/23/a-balancing-act-for-the-matrix-exponential/) a while ago by Cleve Moler about the subject. Is the change related to that?

Comment: I did a quick search, and it seems that [Octave](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/expm.html) implements the same [scale-and-square Padé approximation](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/634/01/covered/MIMS_ep2006_394.pdf) method, while [Python/SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.expm.html) references the newer [2009 paper](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/1442/02/covered/MIMS_ep2009_9.pdf) by *Nick Higham*

Comment: The change to the MATLAB EXPM function was precipitated by encountering an edge case that arose in a control theory application.  However, the change does enable EXPM to get the correct answer on the example that Cleve talked about in his blog post.