# MATLAB Mex function isn't faster than regular function

Tags: c++, performance, matlab, mex

I know that it wont always be the case, but aren't MEX functions supposed to increase efficiency in code, especially with calculations?

I have used the coder toolkit to MEX the `expm` function in MATLAB. I was expecting to see a good increase in efficiency since that function performs a lot of matrix calculations.

However, I don't see much of an improvement in time, as the picture below shows:

[image]

**X-Axis:** Another iteration of `expm` function

**Y-Axis:** Run time for that function

**Blue Line:** Regular `expm` function call

**Red Line:** MEX'ed `expm` function call

Is there a reason that the MEX version is so similar to the regular version? Is there a way to increase the speed? I used `tic` and `toc` to gather data about run time.

Comment: 1) Could you report mean/average values, or plot a histogram of their differences? 2) How large are the matrices you used to test the speed? What if you increase the size of the matrices?

Comment: You'll find that in most cases the algorithm is the most important factor.  It is probable that in your tests, the overhead of loading/using the mex is equivalent to the overhead of the function in Matlab, but I cant tell without a) a working copy of matlab and b) more info on what your tests were.  It uas been my experience both that Matlab functions are pretty well optimised in general, and that some matlab functions are not translated to efficient C/Cpp without some manual optimisation.

Comment: @George On average the size of the matrices range from 12x12 to maybe 18x18 but this is on average. There are outliers as well.

Comment: Even if the compiled version is more efficient than the non-compiled one (although I doubt that, see Mikael's answer), I would not expect it to perform better for such small cases, because of the overhead of calling the MEX functions. Have you tried it with larger matrices, say with hundreds or thousands of rows/columns?

Comment: @GBoggs: it also depends on the settings you used to generate the C code in MATLAB Coder (did you use fixed-size matrices? there's also a "speed" tab in project settings where you can enable certain optimizations). You should post more details about how you compiled the function, as well the code you used to benchmark...

Answer (score 3):

Most matlab functions are simple wrappers that call FORTRAN library code, most of which come from LAPACK / EISPACK / LINPACK. In other words, a built-in matlab function call is already invoking compiled code, not interpreted matlab code (.m sources). So, there isn't much that MEX can do to improve the performance of those function calls.

Compiling your code in matlab will only provide benefits when you have a lot of work being done in matlab source code directly. If your code is mostly invoking a bunch of built-in matlab functions, especially matrix functions (which are all LAPACK functions), then you won't see much improvement, it is only when you have "manual" code, i.e., if you were implementing something like "expm" entirely in matlab code (in a .m file), then it would be much faster when compiled with MEX. You will only see the benefit of compilation of matlab code if you have a significant amount of matlab code of your own, not if you're just making a few calls to built-in functions.

Just think about it, why would Mathworks ship Matlab with built-in functions implemented as interpreted matlab code? Even if they implement some of their built-in functions in matlab code (which is only a small fraction, as most is it FORTRAN / C / C++), they will compile those functions before shipping, so that you, as a user, get the best performance out of them.

Comment: `edit expm`? The function is *not* a native function. However, it's not a particularly complicated function – most of the heavy lifting is done by the call to `mldivide`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how a call to `expm(A)` breaks down where `A = rand(500,500);`.

[image]

The time is split evenly between a matrix multiplication (`F = F*F;`) and a call to the child function `PadeApproximantOfDegree`.  The **matrix multiplication is built in, using very fast LAPACK functions** in mkl.dll (MATLAB's linear algebra functions using Intel MKL).

Here's where all the time is spent in `PadeApproximantOfDegree`:

[image]

**That's not in a loop**.  All calls to built-in matrix math functions.  If there were iterations, then I'd expect MATLAB to be a bit slower, but it's just a few lines with **1 call each** taking up all the time.  Only the matrix multiplication in the parent (`F*F`) is called more than once.

In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if the MEX version were slower, if Coder were not able to use the optimized multi-threaded libraries that MATLAB has access to. Apparently Coder manages.

Comment: it was [confirmed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26472235/97160) in OP's last question that both MATLAB and MATLAB Coder implement the same algorithm (Padé approximation with scaling and squaring) to compute matrix exponential (although a small change in recent versions has apparently not yet been ported to MATLAB Coder). In fact when I tried it last time, MATLAB Coder had generated C code that calls BLAS/LAPACK functions (`dgemm`, `dtstrm`, etc..), which should eventually be compiled against Intel MKL library that ships with MATLAB.

Comment: .. So I expect them to be of similar performance, since they end up calling the same computational routines from MKL (also with JIT compilation in MATLAB it should speeds up basic loops in M-code to get near native performance). If MEX was slightly slower in the OP's tests, I would attribute that simply to the overhead involved in calling MEX-functions.

Comment: To add to what chappjc and Amro said, the documentation mentions some more [strategies](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/optimize-generated-code.html) and [best practices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/best-practices-for-using-mex-functions-to-accelerate-matlab-algorithms.html) for accelerating code. The first link describes that generating MEX when the runtime is dominated by optimized built-in MATLAB functions generally won't add significant performance improvements.